# failed to change page character set in meta

Tags: html, character-encoding

Code as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
```

But when I browse the page using IE, it still uses its default charset, which is not utf8.

And the page becomes normal only after I set the character set to utf8 manually.

Why the HTML failed to inform browser of its character set?

It's on local file system,I browse it by file:///F:/jobs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be **utf-8** not **utf8**.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the server is specifying an encoding itself. Real HTTP headers take priority.

See http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset

Comment: Can be fixed by either modifying HTTP server configuration (I think AddDefaultCharset directive for apache), or if you're using a scripting language then you can tell it to output the apropriate Content-Type header.

Answer (score 1):

There’s an [order in that the actual character encoding is choosen](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.2.2):

> To sum up, conforming user agents must observe the following priorities when determining a document's character encoding (from highest priority to lowest):
>
> 1. An HTTP "charset" parameter in a "Content-Type" field.
> 2. A [META](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-META) declaration with "http-equiv" set to "Content-Type" and a value set for "charset".
> 3. The [charset](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-charset) attribute set on an element that designates an external resource.

So your META declaration may not be considered if there’s already a `charset` declaration in the *Content-Type* HTTP header field.